# Regex-xpath-how to extract a substring from string?

Tags: regex, xpath, soapui

I have the following xpath match  in my soapui test suite ,

```
//html/body/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[td/b[text()='NewsV1']]//td[4]/a[1]/@href[1]
```

Result :

http://shortness.com:101115/localnewsv1/info

I want  the expected result as below (it should take the result from http to till the third /)

http://shortness.com:101115/

I have tried the following xpath combined with regular expression

```
tokenize(/html/body/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[td/b[text()='NewsV1']]//td[4]/a[1]/@href[1], ' ' )[matches(., 'http://+w[a-zA-Z0-9.]+d{*}+/')
```

This gives me an invalid expression in the result.if you have idea point the issue or suggest.

[Screenshot for the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ERj0.png)

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/F1plDY/1

Comment: i am still getting the same error as invalid expression .it may be problem with the syntax i tried for tokenize.can you please align the syntax inside the xpath i given.

xpath i tried now, 

tokenize(//html/body/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[td/b[text()='NewsV1']]//td[4]/a[1]/@href[1], ' ')[matches(., 'http:\/{2}[^\/]+\/')]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this markup,

```
<a href="http://shortness.com:101115/localnewsv1/info"/>
```

this XPath 2.0 expression (make sure your library supports XPath 2.0),

```
concat(join(tokenize(/a/@href, '/' )[position() < 4],'/'),'/')
```

will return

```
http://shortness.com:101115/
```

as requested.

Comment: i am getting the result as invalid xpath expression for the below xpath, 
concat(join(tokenize(added the xpath for fetching the markup, '/' )[position() < 4],'/'),'/')

Comment: Then your XPath processor doesn't support XPath 2.0.  I suggest that you find one that does -- string manipulation is painful in XPath 1.0.  Note that `matches()` also requires XPath 2.0, so you won't be able to use regex either.

Comment: i tried the concat method with  below expression

concat(//html/body/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[td/b[text()='NewsSV1']]//td[4]/a[1]/@href[1],'_',//html/body/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[td/b[text()='NewsV1']]//td[4]/a[1]/@href[1])

will return

http://shortness.com:101115/ gives two times in the result so i feel concat is working then obviously some chances there i have xpath 2.0

Answer (score 1):

I guess that `d{*}` might have a meaning in some regex dialects but it has no meaning (and is invalid) in the XPath 2.0 regex dialect.

Comment: yeah can you give some example of xpath+regular expression.i am not able to find any link exactly.

Comment: There's a whole chapter on regular expressions in my book (XSLT 2.0 and XPath 2.0 Programmer's Reference). But if you don't want to pay for it, you can read the spec. You'll need https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/ section 5.6.1, which defines XPath regular expressions in terms of differences from XSD regular expressions, which in turn are described in https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/ appendix H.

Comment: the document you shared very useful.just now saw your link and  started reading that immediately after seeing this.lot more to learn and understand.so far i can use replace function(my string ,my string pattern,expeceted string pattern) I believe this will work let me try